# Row Level Security on a Paginated report

Tags: azure-active-directory, powerbi, azure-analysis-services, row-level-security, powerbi-paginated-reports

I have a Power BI report which has a button with link to a Power BI paginated report. The Power BI report is sourcing data from an Azure Analysis Service(AAS) and has Row Level Security(RLS) applied to it. I want to make sure that the paginated report also has the RLS applied. I am struggling with the process to apply RLS on the paginated report for Azure Active Directory(AAD).
The AAS has roles based on AAD. How do I apply same RLS (by AAD) on the paginated report?

Would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Currently RLS only works on report server or database side, you can't enable RLS on paginated report
What we can do here is we can embed the paginated report and when you embed a paginated report, you can control which data is displayed. This allows tailoring the displayed information per user. For example, if you have a Power BI paginated report that includes global sale results, you can embed it so that only the sale results from a certain region are available.

This feature provides a secure way of displaying a subset of the data, in a way that doesn't compromise the rest of data. It resembles the [Row Level Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embedded-row-level-security) feature, which provides a secure way of displaying data in Power BI reports (that are not paginated), dashboards, tiles, and datasets.

When applying row-level security to a Power BI paginated report, you need to assign a [Perameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/paginated-reports/report-builder-parameters) to the UserID attribute. This parameter will restrict the data pulled from the dataset, before the report is embedded.

Here is the reference doc to [Use row-level security with Power BI embedded analytics content - Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/paginated-reports-row-level-security)

Comment: This makes sense. The only thing is the RLS that I have is using Azure Active Directory so wondering if this approach of adding userID parameter would resolve the issue.

Comment: After assigning the parameter to UserID, use the Reports GenerateTokenInGroup API to get the embed token to view or edit the specified report from the specified workspace.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/embed-token/reports-generate-token-in-group.